# Orange - Is it possible to create a new widget based on an existing diagram?

Tags: widget, orange

Let's say I have the following diagram:

[image]

I would like to encapsulate this entire diagram into one widget. Is this possible? (Sometimes I end up using the same diagram structure, and was wondering if I could turn that into a widget)

Answer (score 1):

Like a "macro widget"? No. But you can save this schema and reuse it.

Comment: Yeah a macro widget that has all of those widgets in it, that would be an amazing feature.